# Using preg_match to extract a table

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract a table from HTML, here is the HTML code for the start of the table.

```
<table class='price' id='comp' style='clear:both;display:none'>
```

But when I use this PHP code, no matches are found

```
preg_match("/<table class='price' id='comp' style='clear:both;display:none'>.*?<\/[\s]*table>/s", $buffer, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

As the tables are in the HTML, I guess the problem is with the preg_match statement.

Comment: Do not mix regex with HTML. Use some XML parser instead.

Comment: @hsz Why not? When he need only one value from whole site? Parsing (maybe) invalid HTML will probably use more resources

Comment: try adding `im` modifiers to the end of your regexp (so end would look like: `table>/im"` and let me know it it worked

Comment: [Regex is not for parsing HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.  Don't roll your own regex to extract data from webpages.  If you're absolutely hell-bent on using your own regex to do this, try out [My Regex Tester](http://www.myregextester.com/) (not mine - that just happens to be its name) to easily debug your pattern.  Also, refer to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for reasons why you shouldn't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I cant use the DOM parser as I am using a shared hosting. My regex for this should be simple anyway.

Comment: @user1197941 Why would shared hosting prevent you from using the class I linked?  It's a single PHP file, and its only requirement is having PHP 5.

Answer (score -1):

Guess you need this:

`<table class='price' id='comp' style='clear\:both;display\:none'>[\s\S]*?</table>`

Comment: AFAIK `:` doesn't need escaping in PCRE